# Display json data in angular (with typescript)

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I posted this one before, but there were not many helpful answers

I have JSON file that contains the following data:

```
[{
    "ID": 1030980,
    "Component": "Glikoza (Gluk)",
    "Result": "16",
    "Date": "20.10.2018"
  },
  {
    "ID": 1030980,
    "Component": "Kreatinin (Creat)",
    "Result": "5",
    "Date": "19.10.2018"
  },
  {
    "ID": 1030989,
    "Component": "Urea (UN)",
    "Result": "1",
    "Date": "19.10.2018"
  },
  ...this goes on and on
]
```

UPDATE: I added this code to my patients.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-patients',
templateUrl: './patients.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./patients.component.css']
})

export class PatientsComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Patient Data';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
    .get('./assets/patients.json')
    .subscribe(res => {
      const patients = res['patients'];
      const patient = patients[0];
      for (let i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
        let item = patients[i];
        console.log(item['ID'], item['date'], item['component'], item['result']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, I need to take the 'component' and 'result' by Patient ID and by Date in a row (show the results for each component for different date and ID). The table should show ALL OF THE COMPONENTS AND RESULTS for the specific ID and Date, it should look like this:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krkpr.png)

Could you please give me some pointer? Thanks!

Comment: you can use a nested `ngFor` to easily do that. If you can provide a pastebin link with full json I will create a stackblitz

Comment: Thank you @JacopoSciampi, Here is the link http://dpaste.com/0GQZ9SV . At the moment I only need to show the data in the console with typescript.

Comment: This json struct is kinda strange. I'll make an answer as soon I've coded this

Comment: Thanks again @JacopoSciampi, I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Crap, it took me an hour ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it.

Here's the stackblitz : https://angular-aqfdrs.stackblitz.io

[image]

**What i've done**

I've created a dynamic array of array based on the date and the fields you want to be displayed :

```
public patArray: any[] = [];

this.pat[0].patients.forEach(el => {
      if(this.currentDateString == ""){
        this.currentDateString = el['date'];
        if(!this.skipAssign){
          this.patArray[this.idx] = [];
        }
      }

      if(this.currentDateString == el['date']){
        this.patArray[this.idx].push(el);
      } else {
        this.currentDateString = "";
        this.idx++;
        this.patArray[this.idx] = [];
        this.patArray[this.idx].push(el);
        this.skipAssign = true;
      }
    });
```

Then a nested ngFor with some flex do the tricks:

```
.flex-ctr{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.tbl{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:75px;
  height:80px;
}

.table-things{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.bb{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  height:30%;
}

.ss{
  padding-top: 30px;
}

<div class="flex-ctr">
  <div class="first" *ngFor="let data of patArray">
    <div class="tbl" *ngFor="let single of data">
      <div class="table-things">
        <div class="bb">{{single.component}}</div>
        <div class="ss">{{single.result}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad pagination, but I believe is a thing you can adapt to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have already achieved you are darn close.

## 1. Create a type for patients (Model)

```
export class Patient {
    constructor(public ID: string,
        //ALL THE PROPERTIES OF THE MODEL
    ) {}
}
```

## 2. Bind the model to your Component

- Inside your *patients.component.ts*:

  `private patients : Patient[] = [];`

Before subscribing to the get method on the `httpclient`. Place your component in a variable so that you can set the model on it:

```
var self = this; //This is now the PatientsComponent variable
this.http
    .get('./assets/patients.json')
    .subscribe(res => {
      let patients = res['patients'];
      let patient = patients[0];
      self.patients = patients; //SETTING THE MODEL ON THE COMPONENT
      for (let i = 0; i < patients.length; i++) {
        let item = patients[i];
        console.log(item['ID'], item['date'], item['component'], item['result']);
      }
    });
```

## 3. Build your html template with *ngFor

Inside patients.component.html (edit - bind a list of Components to the component class called `components`):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th> 
    <th>Date</th>
    <th *ngFor="let component of components">{{ component }}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let patient of patients">
        <td>{{ patient.ID }}</td>
        <td>{{ patient.Date}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let component of components"> {{ (patient.Component === component) ? patient.Result : "-" }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## 4. [EDIT] Filter our Patient Results

```
public static FilterFunc(patients : Patient[]) {
    let uniques: Patient[] = [];

    patients.forEach(function (value: Patient, index: number) { 
        if (uniques.some(function (patientCompare: Patient) {
            return (patientCompare.Date === value.Date && patientCompare.ID === value.ID && patientCompare.Component === value.Component);
        })) {
            let updatePatient = uniques.find(function (patientCompare: Patient) {
                return (patientCompare.Date === value.Date && patientCompare.ID === value.ID && patientCompare.Component === value.Component);
            });

            updatePatient.Result += value.Result;
        }
        else { 
            uniques.push(value);
        }
    });

}
```

So in our edit you need to also bind a `components : string[];` object to the component. Which must contain `["crea", "gluk", etc....]`

And use the filter function to filter out your data.

Comment: Hmm, but this will display four columns with data (id, component, result, date), right?

Comment: No - currrently this code will display 1 column with header ID and X rows, where X is the number of patients. remember TR's are rows. and TD's are columns.

Comment: Yes, but I need to display results like this

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krkpr.png

The table should show ALL OF THE COMPONENTS AND RESULTS for the specific ID and Date. :)

Comment: So in stack overflow the point is not to let somebody else do the coding for you. It is to teach you. If you can't surmise what to do from the answer above you are of course welcome to say so - but surely you can at least try to think about this and make some deductions of your own?

Comment: You are right, and I need someone to teach me how to take all of the components in the json array for a specific ID, I am not looking for someone to do what you assumed. Thank you

Comment: Thank you a lot, that helped! :)